# Is it ever appropriate to leave the 0 index of an array empty to correspond to real values in the program's front-end?

Tags: java, arrays

I am creating a game with multiple players between 2 and 8. I could use an array from size 8 to fit 8 players in, but I could also create an array of size 9 and leave all the calculations necessary to convert a number to and index.

For me it feels sillier to do many simple calculations like `int index = playerNumber - 1` then to deal with the fact that `arrayExample[0]` is not being used. Is this rare to actually see this being used in code?

Comment: Developers we count from 0 ;-) I know the rest of the world start from 1 .. question of taste

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although there is nothing wrong with leaving some array elements unused, I think that using an array in that way shows a deeper problem with the design: it is reusing a player number, which belongs to the *view* portion of your program, as an index into an array, which belongs to the *model* portion of your program (in MVC sense). This is fragile, because if you change player numbers to, say, player names or player colors, you would have to change the indexing scheme as well.

That's why I would recommend treating array indexes and player numbers as belonging to different domains that do not intersect.

Answer (score 3):

I would say other developers would find it confusing that the first element is being left empty.
On the other hand so long as you are clear in your code it is your choice.

That said, I would probably use a Map rather than an array, that way I can map player number to the player object and not worry about missing elements in an array or the maths to zero index the player number.

Answer (score 3):

By convention, array elements start at index 0. I think that taking the convention of having the zero-index element empty leads to code that is error-prone, as most loops are written in a way that starts at zero index.

Plus the fact that an element takes unneeded space in memory and the size of the array is not equal to the actual number of users.

Answer (score 1):

How many such arrays would you have? If its less than a 100, i wold not worry about it. Even a 100 empty places will just be empty references and not take up more than a few bytes.

I have coded like that when i was starting out. But changed when people reading the code had issues and more energy went on explaining to them vs -1 in the code.

BTW  playerNumber-- seems dangerous. You just want the correct reference number or change the player number in that variable too?

Why not :

```
 index = playerNumber - 1;
```

This way your player number wont be changed. Unless you mean to change it as its a local variable?